# HTML5 Audio play instantly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm creating the application that plays live mp3 stream from server. 
Basically it's node.js server which pipes PulseAudio output encoded as mp3 to browser using HTTP. On browser side it's simple HTML5 audio element.
I want to have as little latency as possible. Unfortunately simple html5 audio element introduces about 8 seconds (250 kilobytes) of lag (starts playing 8 seconds after first byte was downloaded) using Chrome browser. I assume that it's some kind of buffer but I can't find any information about how to tweak it.

Is there a way to change this buffer length? I'd like it to be as short as 0.5-1 second, not 8.

Comment: AFAIK you can't tweak the audio tag. You can download the data yourself in chunks and pass it to the Audio API which I believe is what soundcloud does. If you go to soundcloud you'll notice audio plays quickly. If you open the devtools and look at the network tab you'll see the individual requests